# "Use 'indexes' instead.", DeprecationWarning)

Tags: python, django, django-mongodb-engine

I practice [The Django Book Chapter 10: Advanced Models](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html) and have problem

I copy these code below in my model.py,and then run `python manage.py sqlall books`
 in termial as the website said,but there are errors.

Is it because my database is django-mongodb-engine?

```
/Users/wi/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/creation.py:98:   
DeprecationWarning: 'descending_indexes', 'sparse_indexes' and 'index_together' are 
deprecated and will be ignored as of version 0.6. Use 'indexes' instead.
"Use 'indexes' instead.", DeprecationWarning)

Installing indices for books.Publisher model.
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: I think because mongodb is not SQL and Django has no officially support for it, that command doesn't work. If you are learning, try the most simple posible setup with sqlite.

Comment: I am supposed to use mongodb as a part of the project. What can be the possible answer to this error?Here is the link for my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202928/error-while-syncdb-django-mongo